# SignalR and Missing messages

Tags: signalr

I have created a MVC3 web application that uses SignalR as the chat service. I have implemented it using the Hub, I have noticed that from time to time the clients gets disconnected and when and then does not receive all of the chat messages.

I have seen it reconnect but does not get all of the messages for the period that it was disconnected. I have read that the messages are stored in process and that they are cleared is there any way that I can set the amount of time that the messages stay in memory.

Or is there an event that I can use to determine when I reconnect and then go get the lost messages?

Comment: Are you using 0.4? It *should* never miss messages. What environment are you running in? What webserver/OS? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes I am using 0.4 I am using the Hub implementation and no I am not binding to a proxy

Comment: File a bug on github with repro steps.